# Opening subtab with Lightning Component from Visualforce

Tags: service-cloud-console, tab, service-console

I include a Visualforce in the lightning record page of Account and I would like to open new subtab in the same service console with a lightning component.

Is it possible to do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a Summer 18 feature which allows opening lightning component as a new tab.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_lc_components_navigation.htm

You can also consider the subtab from the VF page using the JS
"sforce.console.openSubtab" . But it will only open the URL so you may need to embed your custom lightning component to a VF page and then use the VF URL in the above function.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_opensubtab.htm